# Socket.on triggered succesfully after first emit but not on second emit,

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets

`I am connecting the socket io successfully and also listener event triggered get the response on first emit but when i emit another object onNewMessage not triggered,at server side socket successfully responded but onNewMessage not triggered.`

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var mSocket: Socket? = null
var url: String = "https://brainbehind.co:1000"

```
var button: Button? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val opts = IO.Options()
    opts.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
    mSocket = IO.socket(url, opts)

   //listener event to get response from the server
    mSocket?.on("reply_from_bot", onNewMessage)


    mSocket?.connect()


    //First emit to connect with the server
    val obj = JSONObject()
    obj.put("room", System.currentTimeMillis())
    obj.put("chatfrom", "2")
    obj.put("message", "start")
    obj.put("clientid", 2)
    obj.put("botid", 2)

    mSocket?.emit("connect_client_to_bot", obj)


}
```

//This is the listener to collect the response, it is triggered and print the response first time but when i emit mSocket?.emit("send_msg_to_bot", obj) , it is not triggered, but when i see the server side socket response successfully triggered but i am not able to listen in this event, also tried to make another event but does not work for me also
private val onNewMessage = Emitter.Listener { args ->
runOnUiThread(Runnable {

```
        val data = args[1] as JSONObject
        Log.d("TAG", data.toString())

        // Emit another object 
        val obj = JSONObject()
        obj.put("room", System.currentTimeMillis())
        obj.put("chatfrom", "2")
        obj.put("message", "Get HealthAssist")
        obj.put("clientid", 2)
        obj.put("botid", 2)
        obj.put("step", "1")
        mSocket?.emit("send_msg_to_bot", obj)
    })
}
```

`onNewMessage event triggered correctly after this mSocket?.emit("connect_client_to_bot", obj) but not triggered after this  mSocket?.emit("send_msg_to_bot", obj) even server gives response correctly.stuck in this from last weak, also created a new socket.on() event but this was also not worked.`